# Could I define an isothermal efficiency?

Tags: thermodynamics, compressors

There's an adiabatic efficiency because real processes can't be adiabatic.

I want an isothermal compression (yes, I know an adiabatic compression consumes less work, but my pressure differential is too high and a high temperature rise is undesired).

I know real compressions can't be isothermal because there will always be a higher or lower temperature rise.

How could I define it? Something like this?

$\eta_{iso}=1-\Delta T/Factor$

But how could apply this to my compressor? I can't apply it directly as if it were the adiabatic efficiency, which is based on theorical vs. real enthalpy jump.

I just came up with this idea: What about multiplying the isothermal work by $1+\Delta T/Factor$ to get the real compression work?

Comment: If there is a temperature change then it is not an isothermal process...

Comment: If there is an entropy change then it is not an adiabatic process, but we use adiabatic processes and adiabatic efficiecies.

Comment: What do you understand by the word / term "isothermal" ?

Comment: Of course I do, the temperature is constant. But we use adiabatic formulae to calculate the compression work and add an adiabatic efficiency because the process isn't adiabatic.

Comment: An adiabatic process is one where heat does not flow between system and surroundings. But the process itself can lead to an entropy change due to irreversibilities. An isothermal process has no temperature change from initial to final state. Is your process really isothermal?

Comment: No, it is not. But I want to use the isothermal formulae. Could I use them and divide by 0.80 to get the real compression work, for example?

Comment: Maybe dividing by 0.8 is incorrect because other processes rather than isothermal (e.g., adiabatic) consume less work than isothermal.

Comment: The fundamentals of isothermal, adiabatic, reversible, and irreversible processes are not something that can be dismissed simply with “no it is not”. I have to downvote this question because the clarity of background research is lacking.